# Increase a partition without data loss

Tags: fdisk, sles

If there is a partition, ex.:

```
/dev/sdb1
```

Then how can I increase the partition (with fdisk?), if it was 10 GByte before, and there are still place to increase the partition with another 10 GByte, so sum: how can I increase the partition's size from 10 GByte to 20 GByte? Without data loss! - so re-creating the partition is not a solution.

UPDATE: thought there will be a command to modify the partitions end to a new end, so yes, re-creating the partition is OK! :) the main thing is that data on the partition should stay untouched, without any copy here, than copy it back thing. :)

Comment: Why is deleting the partition not a solution? The only data that is loss is data that you end up re-creating when you specify the larger partition. The files, etc are left intact.

Comment: At the risk of looking Stupid, why not use a [GParted Live Disk](http://gparted.org/livecd.php).  I know it's not `fdisk` but it's easier

Answer (score 1):

If the space behind the partition is free, just `umount` the partition, delete it and recreate it with the same start block, but the bigger size.

Then resize the filesystem on the partition to the new size and remount.

As long as you create the start of the partition in the same spot you will not lose data. Some filesystems you can mount first and then resize (increase in size).